# Python when a list isn't a list? list object has no attribute split

Tags: python

I have a list of user ids being sent to my API:

```
Users = ['x1','x2']
```

In my serializer create method I try to iterate over them:

```
    users = validated_data.get('users', None)
    for user in users:
        print(user)
        print("===")
```

The output I receive is:

```
> x1,x2
> ===
```

It instead of iterating over the list, it outputs as one line! This suggests to me it is not a list, but a string, so I checked the `type(users)` which gave a blank i.e. no type.

So I tried splitting users up `users.split()` Then I get a contradiction" "**list object has no attribute split**"!

What is wrong here, confused?

Comment: Are you using django? Where is validated_data defined? That will give a clue as to what the return type of that method is.

Comment: It is true, lists don't have split. Only strings do.

Comment: What framework are you using? You're talking about ListSerializer... is this django rest framework?

Comment: @Moshe I'm using ListField from Django rest http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield

Comment: @James Yes so it is def a list, but won't let me loop correctly. I'm using http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield

Comment: Looks like ``ListField`` in DRF treats it as a string then!

Comment: I'm looking through the validation methods now, and that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Moshe For whatever reason it is receiving it as a string ``['[1,2]']``

Comment: What kind of field is Users?

Comment: @Moshe is a  ``users = serializers.ListField()``

Comment: I'm asking about `Users`, your first line of code.

Comment: @Moshe sorry I misunderstand, it's a list ``type(users)``. Users come from a post cURL shows ``-F "users=[1,2]"``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have pointed out that you seem to have a list containing a single string, `['x1, x2']`.

I took a look at the Django REST Framework internals, and it's definitely returning a list.

[ListField](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L1429) inherits from [Field](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L262), which defines a few methods, including `run_validation`, `to_internal_value`, and `to_representation`.

Two of those methods are abstract, and one of them, `run_validation` actually invokes the validation by calling [self.to_internal_value(data)](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L512).

So to see what the validator is doing, we have to look at the ListField's implementation of `to_internal_value`.

The comment inside of `to_internal_value` says this:

```
"""
    List of dicts of native values <- List of dicts of primitive datatypes.
"""
```

Then it checks for invalid input types and finally, calls `run_validation`.

According to my IDE, there are 5 implementations of `run_validation` in Django REST Framework. The most relevant one is probably `ListSerializer`.

[image: 5 implementations of run_validation]

The comments above [`ListSerializer`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L515) tell us that we're probably in the right place:

```
# There's some replication of `ListField` here,
# but that's probably better than obfuscating the call hierarchy.
```

The `ListSerializer` class [validates each item (source)](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L588) and then appends it to a list called `ret`. So we should be returning a list.

The unsolved piece of the puzzle here is what your input is that is causing the output to be incorrect, but tracing through the call stack, the code appears to be working as intended.

**EDIT:**

Could it be that [to_representation](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L609) is flattening your list because it thinks it's a dictionary?

Comment: Thanks so much for this @Moche it appears that ``to_representation``  and ``to_internal_value`` was the issue! it was making it a string when used with multipart/formdata ! :)

Comment: Glad to help. It might be worth poking around at the html handling in those methods, because that seems to be the special case there.

Comment: Can you tell me which versions of Python and DRF you're using?

Comment: Must be, it appears to only happen on form data post. converting it to raw data json it works ok. again thanks for your time on this.

Comment: I opened an issue about this on the DRF GitHub page: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/4056

Answer (score 2):

It seems that users is a list that looks like this: `['x1,x2']`. Instead of what you expected: `['x1','x2']`

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to make a list first, or you can just split that one element:

```
users = ['x1,x2']
for user in users[0].split(','):
    print(user)
    print('===')
```

Output:

```
>>> users = ['x1,x2']
>>> for user in users[0].split(','):
...    print(user)
...    print('===')


x1
===
x2
===
```

A per your comment:

```
from ast import literal_eval
users = ['[1,2]']

users = literal_eval(users[0])
for user in users:
    print(user)
    print('===')
```

Output:

```
1
===
2
===
```

For `users = ['[x1,x1]']`:

```
users = ['[x1,x1]']
users = users[0][1:-1]

for user in users.split(','):
    print(user)
    print('===')
```

Comment: Even with ``[1,2]`` I still get output ``[1,2]`` instead of 1 === 2 ===

Comment: I'm not sure why I need to do this, it should just be a standard list. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield

Comment: @Spaceships Sorry I forgot to add `','` to `split`. Should work now

Comment: No sure that would work, it will just output ``[x1`` new line ``x2]``

Answer (score 1):

It looks as is `users` is a *list* with a single item `x1,x2`:

```
>>> users = ['x1,x2']
>>> for user in users:
...     print(user)
...     print("===")
... 
x1,x2
===
```

Comment: I'm using ``serializers.ListField()`` to post the data  with no validation error and the data is ``['x1','x2']``, is this not a list? Why would ``type(users)`` also give a blank?

Comment: @Spaceships yeah, weird format. Could you show what `validated_data` is?

Comment: validated_data is the standard DRF here is the output ``{'organisation':1, 'users': ['1,2'], 'message': 'Test', 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=<django.utils.timezone.FixedOffset object at 0x11059c7f0>)}``

Comment: I see that the post is ``['1,2']`` which woudl explain it! but thats not what I'm posting, very strange!

Comment: cURL has ``-F "users=[1,2]" ``

Comment: Looks like ``ListField`` in DRF treats it as a string then!